# Torque (in $Nm$) of a cyclist

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, estimation

We're discussing bicycles with a friend, and it came to safety, speed and power. Now the question we have is: how much torque do my legs provide to the bicycle?

I'm no expert in physics sadly, and the results we came up seem a little on the high side... Here are the calculations:

Based on the formula given on another stack exchange (https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/18199/), the formula for torque is

```
t = r * F
where t = torque in Newton-meters
      r = radius in meters
      F = force in Newton

and

F = w * g
where F = force in Newton
      w = weight
      g = gravity
```

Assuming the following:

```
My weight is 65kg
Gravity is still 9.81 m/s²
My bicycle cranks (the pedal levers) are 170mm long
```

Then, assuming I'm standing on one pedal, I end up with the following:

```
t = 0.17 * (65 * 9.81)
  = 108.40
```

108.40Nm seems like a very large value, especially assuming that my big bad motorcycle develops "only" 63Nm. So is that all correct, or is there something wrong somewhere?

And if that's correct, how come I can't go faster than my motorcycle?

Comment: Where is the 63 N$\cdot$m value coming from?

Comment: Peak torque of the engine, around 6-7000 RPM.

Comment: And there you have the difference. Your engine produces 7000rpm for hours, a good cyclist at the top of his performance maybe 200rpm for a couple minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you pedal at about 100 rpm (I don't know what a typical rate of pedalling is, but this seems a plausible order of magnitude).

To make a fair comparison with your motorbike you need to gear the moorbike engine down from 7,000 rpm to the same 100 rpm that you pedal at, i.e. a factor of 70, and this will multiply the torque by a factor of 70. So at 100 rpm your motorbike engine would be producing a torque of 4,410 Nm or about a factor of 40 greater than the torque you can produce.

That's why the motorbike can accelerate faster than your bicycle can.

Comment: Interesting point. I guess the factor you're referring to is the gearbox then (or transmission demultiplication in general), is that so? Btw yes, 100rpm is plausible. Actually we're targeting 90rpm, but going upto 120rpm is common.

Comment: Also, that measure of torque * rpm is horsepower if I'm correct? That would explain quite a few things in my mind at least.

Comment: Yes, torque times angular frequency = power

Comment: I think there may be another factor of two in there in favor of the motorcycle engine. The cyclist can only produce torque by pushing down on the paddles, but it's virtually impossible to produce any in the 12 and 6 o'clock positions, so that's another cosine averaging out to a factor of two less torque on average, right? I don't think the engine has that problem, since the torque spec should be an average over a full cycle.

Comment: @CuriousOne: yes, an accurate comparison would be more complicated than the simple analsys I've done. Note that serious cyclists use toe clips that allow them to pull up as well as push down, as well as pushing forward when the pedal at the top and backwards when the pedal is at the bottom.

Comment: @JohnRennie: That's true, it might be less than the factor of two, then.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a vector formula with cross product.  Let's switch to this:

t = r * F * sin theta, where theta is the angle between your leg and the lever on the sprocket wheel.  Theta will change depending on where you are in the cycle of pedaling your bike.  Greatest value for sin theta will be when the sprocket crank is horizontal and your leg is perpendicular to it.

For force, use your mass rather than your weight in the formula:

F = m * g

Plugging in your numbers:

F = 65 * 9.81 = 637

t = .17 * 637 * 1 = 108 newtons

You got the correct torque.  But your motorcycle has a flywheel which stores energy and rotates at a much faster rate than the sprocket wheel on your bicycle.  The flywheel inertia is much greater than your sprocket wheel, and the motorcycle engine can keep pumping much faster and much longer than you can.  You can't match your motorcycle's RPM.  That's why your motorcycle has more power than your bicycle.

Your bicycle is higher torque with lower speed, and your motorcycle is lower torque with higher speed.

Comment: Ah, there you go, I didn't see your comment, but I agree, cyclists are only producing half the max. torque on average.

Comment: Note that with toe clips on the pedals you can produce torque on the upstroke and the horizontal strokes, too. (It's kind of awesome.)